# JSON parsing in Grails

Tags: regex, json, grails, groovy

In my grails application, i'm invoking thirdparty REST api which returns JSON in which i may have HTML content as a property value. For example, something like this:

```
{
  "presentationData": {
  "id": "123-45",
  "placeholders": [
   {
    "transition": "fade",
    "items": [
     {
      "name": "Text Item",
      "objectData": "<font face=\\"Palatino Linotype, Book Antiqua, Palatino, serif\\" size=\\"7\\">TEXT TEXT TEXT</font>",
      "timeDefined": "false"
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
 }
```

I'm unable to parse this JSON in grails: getting exception at:
`"objectData": "<font face=\\"Palatino Linotype, Book Antiqua, Palatino, serif\\" size=\\"7\\">TEXT TEXT TEXT</font>",`

due to `\\` characters in the value.

I tried below code:

```
JSONElement scriptJson=JSON.parse(resp)
```

and even with JsonSlurper:

```
JsonSlurper slurper=new JsonSlurper()
def scriptJson=slurper.parseText(resp)
```

Both are failing at same value.

I tried to replace, `\\` with `\` before parsing but couldn't make it work:

```
resp=resp.replaceAll(/\\+/,/\/)
```

Getting compilation error, where as if i try replace with any other character,`#`, otherthan `/` its getting replaced:

```
resp=resp.replaceAll(/\\+/,/#/)
```

giving output as:

```
<font face=#"Palatino Linotype, Book Antiqua, Palatino, serif#" size=#"7#">TEXT TEXT TEXT</font>
```

So i need solution for either:

parsing this invalid JSON or replacing `\\` with `\` in groovy.

I'm struggling for this for the past two days. Please help me out.

Comment: Try resp=resp.replaceAll(/\\+/,/'/)

Comment: @BZ, it is replacing with single quote`'`. But i want to get replaced with single backward slash, ` \ `. I think i conveyed the same in my question too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok. After several trial and errors, finally this worked:

```
resp.replaceAll(/\\+/,'\\\\')
```

which is giving output as:

```
<font face=\"Palatino Linotype, Book Antiqua, Palatino, serif\" size=\"7\">TEXT TEXT TEXT</font>
```

Now both `JSON.parse(resp)` and `slurper.parseText(resp)` are working fine without any errors.

I'm still thinking there might be better solution than this. Anyways, i don't have much time now and so i'm going with this solution.